# cannot connect to gitlab registry

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to connect to a gitlab registry , but I get connection failure
(I am able to connect normally with `docker login` from my shell, using user + PAT)

plus, the gitlab option is not present (see picture below), as said here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-container-registries
(instead, github is present, next to docker hub, azure, generic v2)

[image]

ps: on :

- vs-code v1.84.2
- docker ext v1.28.0
- linux mint 21.2

Comment: Can you post the exact command you used to log in (redact credentials please) as well as the output?

Comment: using the command it works 
I am trying to use the ext: is it possible to connect to gitlab via the etx?  , because indeed  the gitlab option is not presend

Comment: follow up in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/4182

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the generic registry, you might have to add the port `5000` (standard registry port).
If you need more assistance, please post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: ok, but then how the url should look like? 
https://registry.gitlab.com/ nor https://registry.gitlab.com/:5000 is working ... (404)

Comment: Try `https://registry.gitlab.com` or `https://registry.gitlab.com:5000` (the port needs to be right after the tld, not after the slash).

Comment: please, follow https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/4182